# maas nodes login incorrect

Tags: 12.04, juju, maas

I'm testing Ubuntu12.04 MAAS with juju ,i installed the maas server and add 2 nodes 
now the nodes allocated to admin user when i start them login is required i tried the admin username and password but always got error "login incorrect" any one can help me please

Answer (score 1):

```
juju ssh <machine-id>
```

...is easiest , and:

```
ssh ubuntu@<host>
```

...is roughly equivalent. You'll always need to log in as the `ubuntu` user, and you'll need to authenticate with one of the private keys (`id_dsa`, `id_rsa`, or `identity`) in your `~/.ssh` directory.

(When you bootstrapped, juju will have looked in `~/.ssh` and automatically chosen one of `id_dsa.pub`, `id_rsa.pub` and `identity.pub` to authorize for all machines; if necessary, you can override this behaviour by setting `authorized-keys-path` in your environment configuration, but you may need to do more work to configure ssh to use the appropriate private keys.)

Comment: thank you very much 
i tried juju ssh <machine-id> but got ERROR no reachable servers
also tried ssh ubuntu@<host> and got 
ssh: Could not resolve hostname node0: Name or service not known
i tried enter the username 'ubuntu' and admin's username and pw but also got login incorrect
i didn't understand what to do with ssh key i already configured

Comment: It sounds as though your machine can't see the maas network. Try adding a nameserver as [described here](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/configure.html#client-side-dns-configuration).